# Is adding 1 to a number repeatedly slower than adding everything at the same time in C++?

Tags: c++

If I have a number a, would it be slower to add 1 to it b times rather than simply adding a + b?

```
a += b;
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
  a += 1;
}
```

I realize that the second example seems kind of silly, but I have a situation where coding would actually be easier that way, and I am wondering if that would impact performance.

EDIT: Thank you for all your answers. It looks like some posters would like to know what situation I have. I am trying to write a function to shift an inputted character a certain number of characters over (ie. a cipher) if it is a letter. So, I want to say that one char += the number of shifts, but I also need to account for the jumps between the lowercase characters and uppercase characters on the ascii table, and also wrapping from z back to A. So, while it is doable in another way, I thought it would be easiest to keep adding one until I get to the end of a block of letter characters, then jump to the next one and keep going.

Comment: Can't you write a benchmark in about 30 seconds that would test this and tell you whether it makes any difference? You already have the code, basically. (And a loop is always going to take longer than a single addition; how much longer would depend on many things including compiler optimizations. Whether the performance difference would be meaningful or not is also subject to actual use.)

Comment: I think it's useful to mention what your use-case or programming context is where the second form is easier to work with than the first.

Comment: Doing something n times usually tends to be n times slower, welcome to common sense. Also, the computer doesn't really care about how big values are, 1 + 1 is just as fast as 1000000 + 1000000. That loop is very simple though, and unless optimizations are disabled, the compiler should generate code similar to the first case.

Comment: If you have a real-world situation, you should show it (or at least some simplified version of it).  Otherwise, your question is silly.

Comment: @KenWhite if he's asking this, he probably doesn't know how to use timers.

Comment: @ddriver it's not necessarily n times slower. `a += b` uses an `add` instruction. The loop uses b `inc` instructions, which I believe are faster than `add`s. True, this neglects the `jmp`, but then there's branch prediction, unrolling, etc...

Comment: @MillieSmith - IIRC 99% of the time both are a single clock. The increment instruction is shorter because it has only one operand.

Comment: @ddriver [Yeah, you're right](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf)

Comment: @KenWhite Maybe - but the time I get probably won't have much significance unless I add some huge numbers, and I thought that the numbers I would have to add would be bigger than the maximum int value in C++

Comment: Then you've answered your own question. "the time I get probably won't have much significance". Therefore, either of them would work for you, and it's a matter of preference (although why you'd ever find a need to loop rather than directly incrememt if you know the value is unclear). You've also included information in your last comment that isn't apparent in the question (regarding the max int value). The info in your edit doesn't help (it's still unclear what you're doing), but there is never a time when you should loop if a direct addition is possible. An addition is 1 opcode.

Comment: @MillieSmith This isn't for a timer, see my edit for the actual situation. Thank you for your point about the increment vs add instructions, that was very insightful.

Comment: @KenWhite Fair enough. I've included the actual situation I'm talking about in an edit. And I meant the numbers that I would have to add in a benchmark, not the numbers I am actually adding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language C++ does not describe how long either of those operations take.  Compilers are free to turn your first statement into the second, and that is a legal way to compile it.

In practice, many compilers would treat those two subexpressions as the same expression, assuming everything is of type `int`.  The second, however, would be fragile in that seemingly innocuous changes would cause massive performance degradation.  Small changes in type that 'should not matter', extra statements nearby, etc.

It would be extremely rare for the first to be slower than the second, but if the type of `a` was such that `+= b` was a much slower operation than calling `+= 1` a bunch of times, it could be.  For example;

```
struct A {
  std::vector<int> v;
  void operator+=( int x ) {
    // optimize for common case:
    if (x==1 && v.size()==v.capacity()) v.reserve( v.size()*2 );
    // grow the buffer:
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
      v.reserve( v.size()+1 );
      v.resize( v.size()+1 );
    }
  }
};
```

then `A a; int b = 100000; a+=b;` would take much longer than the loop construct.

But I had to work at it.

Comment: "compilers are free to turn your first statement into the second" don't you mean the opposite?

Comment: @ddrive The C++ standard lets a compiler compile `a += b` into a loop which increments `a`: I meant that way.  I did not mention the other way around.  And yes, it also lets them convert the loop into a simple increment, but the point of that phrase was to point out how little the C++ standard constrains compilers.

Answer (score 3):

If your loop is really that simple, I don't see any reason why a compiler couldn't optimize it. I have no idea if any actually *would*, though.  If your compiler doesn't the single addition will be *much* faster than the loop.

Comment: Exactly. As a specific heuristic built in the compiler, it's certainly possible, but who would write code like that? Otherwise, what would be the general algorithm? The compiler has to detect that the operations are all applied in sequence inconditionally (there's already a condition there on the loop sequence).

Comment: "Much faster" is relative. The loop is by no means slow for small b.

Comment: @Millie - at least 2x, right?

Answer (score 1):

The overhead (CPU instructions) on having a variable being incremented in a loop is likely to be insignificant compared to the total number of instructions in that loop (unless the only thing you are doing in the loop is incrementing). Loop variables are likely to remain in the low levels of the CPU cache (if not in CPU registries) and is very fast to increment as in doesn't need to read from the RAM via the FSB. Anyway, if in doubt just make a quick profile and you'll know if it makes sense to sacrifice code readability for speed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely slower.  The second example is beyond silly.  I highly doubt you have a situation where it would make sense to do it that way.

Lets say 'b' is 500,000... most computers can add that in a single operation, why do 500,000 operations (not including the loop overhead).

Comment: That is always relative to the total computational cost of the loop. In practice sometimes having a more readable code outweighs the insignificant gain in performance.

Comment: I don't get it... he is talking about adding two numbers, doing a loop to increment to that value is absurd.  I'd fire anyone I caught doing it like that. @DarienPardinas

Comment: @RobC Obviously in the example I gave, it doesn't make sense to do that. I guess what I really wanted to know was at the CPU level, does the computer add numbers one at a time or all at once? And in my situation, it really is more readable that way.

Comment: It gets a little complicated but basically if you have an X bit system (eg 16 bit, 32 bit, 64 bit, etc) the architecture can usually do simple operations (at least addition and subtraction) in a single clock cycle if the size <= the system bit base.  Things can get weird with floating point or division. It is all about bit manipulation, so a 64 bit system can almost always do 64 bit manipulations much faster than a 32 bit system.  @UnsolvedCypher

Answer (score 0):

If the processor has an increment instruction, the *compiler* will usually translate the "add one" operation into an increment instruction.

Some processors may have an optimized increment instructions to help speed up things like loops.  Other processors can combine an increment operation with a load or store instruction.

There is a possibility that a small loop containing only an increment instruction could be replaced by a multiply and add.  The compiler is allowed to do so, if and only if the functionality is the same.

This kind of operation, generally produces negligible results.  However, for large data sets and performance critical applications, this kind of operation may be necessary and the time gained would be significant.

**Edit 1:**
For adding values other than 1, the compiler would emit processor instructions to use the best addition operations.

The add operation is optimized in hardware as a different animal than incrementing.  Arithmetic Logic Units (ALU) have been around for a long time.  The basic addition operation is very optimized and a lot faster than incrementing in a loop.